# Authorization error still persists when calling getDataSourceFormula() even after allowing script to acces Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the content of a cell's formula from a custom function that I wrote. I'm just trying to get the formula stored in `B2`. In Google Sheets. I am getting "`Exception: Authorization is required to perform that action. (line 5).`". I tried revoking the authorization, adding the next first three lines and authorizing again. Nothing worked.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function test() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getDataSourceFormula().getFormula();
}
```

I can confirm that the error is coming from `getDataSourceFormula()`. I tried replacing it with other functions, and they worked normally. What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you provided the [necessary authorization scope(s)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#authorization_46)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrectly [getDataSourceFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatasourceformula) as you are combining it with [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula).

`getFormula()` returns the top left cell formula of a range while `getDataSourceFormula()` returns the [DataSourceFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-formula) for the first cell in the range.  Thus, `getDataSourceFormula` will only work for data sources, [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295223?hl=en) is more official information regarding what these are.

As you didn't mention anything about data sources in your question I am assuming that you are not using them and therefore you code line should look like this:

```
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getFormula();
```